# Error: matching constraint not valid in output operand

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, powerpc, altivec

I'm having trouble getting GCC inline assembler to accept some inline assembly for Power9.

The regular assembly I am trying to get GCC to accept is `darn 3, 1`, where `3` is `r3` and `1` is parameter called `L` in the docs. It disassembles to this on big-endian:

```
0:   e6 05 61 7c    darn    r3,1
```

And on little-endian:

```
0:   7c 61 05 e6    darn    r3,1
```

Due to various reasons and problems, including old compilers and compilers that pretend to be other compilers,  I want to issue byte codes for the instruction. My test program:

```
gcc112:~$ cat test.c
#include <stdint.h>

void random()
{
  volatile uint64_t x = __builtin_darn();

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("darn 3, 1");

  uint64_t y;
  __asm__ __volatile__ (".byte 0x7c, 0x61, 0x05, 0xe6  \n" : "=r3" (y));
}
```

Compiling it results in:

```
$ /opt/cfarm/gcc-latest/bin/gcc -mcpu=power9 -c test.c
test.c: In function 'random':
test.c:10:3: error: matching constraint not valid in output operand
   __asm__ __volatile__ (".byte 0x7c, 0x61, 0x05, 0xe6  \n" : "=r3" (y));
   ^~~~~~~
test.c:10:3: error: matching constraint not valid in output operand
test.c:10:3: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 0
```

Here's the section of the GCC inline assembly manual that should cover it, but I don't see it expalined: [6.45.2.3 Output Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands). I also checked simple and machine constraints but did not see it.

How do I tell GCC to execute the instruction, and then move `r3` into `y`?

---

We do the same thing on x86 with `rdrand`. It works without problems on all version of GCC going back to 2.9:

```
uint64_t temp;
__asm__ __volatile__
(
    // radrand rax with retry
    "1:\n"
    ".byte 0x48, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0;\n"
    "jnc 1b;\n"
    : "=a" (temp)
    : : "cc"
);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `r3` as an output constraint.  I'm guessing this is intended to indicated that the output will be in the 'r3' register, but I don't think you can do it this way (although I'm no expert on powerpc's [machine](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) constraints).  Perhaps you could try `register uint64_t y asm("r3");` (ie a [local register variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html)) and then just use `=r` as the constraint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have GCC combine "move r10, r3; store r10" into a "store r3"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491053/how-to-have-gcc-combine-move-r10-r3-store-r10-into-a-store-r3), where I posted basically the same register-asm local variable answer as @David.

Answer (score 1):

*Moving my (untested) comment to an answer to attempt to close this out*

I'm not familiar with `r3` as an output constraint. I'm guessing this is intended to indicate that the output will be in the 'r3' register, but I don't think you can do it this way (although I'm no expert on powerpc's [machine constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html)). Instead, perhaps you could try:

```
register uint64_t y asm("r3");
```

(ie make `y` a [local register variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html)) and then just use "=r" as the constraint?

Comment: Thanks David. I tried both the register local and pointer to register local but neither worked. Both resulted in a wild write that segfault'd the program. The disassembly showed two stores occurring. That's why I want to get `=r3` working as expected (which I don't think is possible).

Comment: Looking at the output from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9gS3oN), I'm seeing the same results for  __builtin_darn that I see for using a local register.  If there's a wild pointer, I'm not convinced it's coming from this code.  Did you remove the 'extra' `__asm__ __volatile__ ("darn 3, 1");`?  That code is invalid as it overwrites r3 without informing the compiler.